# How to install genie effect of Mac OS in my elementary OS？

Tags: release-freya, gui-toolkits

I want to customize my elementary OS  with Genie effect(an animation effect in Mac OS), and its equivalent in Linux is called Magic Lamp.

I have searched for many times about this question in Google, However, There seems that all solutions are the same.

Here are some operations:

- Install 'Compiz config manager'
- Install editor 'ghex'
- Edit three files in '/usr/lib/compiz/' with 'ghex' editor(replace some strings)
- Change the Magic Lamp settings in (System > Preferences > CompizConfig Settings Manager: Animations > the last tab called "Effects Settings"):

Unfortunately, It doesn't work. The problem is when  I operate the third step I couldn't find the strings which are to be replaced. Besides, these solution is a little old and some of them are in 2008 or earlier.

Here are some links about the solution:

- https://ch0yan.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/mac-osx-like-genie-effect-on-ubuntu-12-04/
- http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/get-the-os-x-genie-effect-in-compiz-easily
- http://www.webupd8.org/2009/05/docky-move-it-to-top-of-desktop-add.html

As a result, Is there anyone could provide me a new solution to this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use compiz effects (not at all so this hack might not be useful) in Pantheon/Gala that is in the elementary OS desktop environement.